# Divide a model into 4 equal pieces in blender?

Tags: 3d-printing

I have a 3d model that i need to print using a 3d printer but the 3d printer i have is too small for the model i have. I need to split the model into 4 equal parts so that i can print them individually and then join the pieces somehow.

[image]

This is what the model looks like from the top. It is a circle. How can i achieve this?

Comment: did u try boolean modifiers?

Comment: with the boolean, or if the topology is clean you can easily rip some edge loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Bisect` tool. Go to face edit mode and select all faces, then use bisect. You can just place the bisect gizmo and then focus on the tool dialog where you can precisely define the cutting plane position and orientation and have some options (`Fill`, `Clear Inner`, `Clear outer`) to define the resulting rest of the model. In the screenshot you can see some setting for your use case. Duplicate your model and then apply the bisect twice so you are left with another quarter of your model. Repeat this until you have your 4 separated pieces.

[image]